# How to get checkbox selected values in mvc3 form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

I have a form, in my form user can fill their details and choose their interests that is in checkbox. I place interest section  in a form as a partial view.

Form having,

1. Name
2. Date Of Birth
3. Place
4. Interests (Checkbox list)

I have a model that having all fields Name, BirthDay, Place.
And another model for LookingFormodel.

Now when i submit form. all fields like name, Birthday and palce is comming to model but i am not getting checkbox selected item list.

How can i get checkbox values in form submit?

Comment: Can you show us some code?
ASP.NET MVC 3 is perfectly able to map your form fields automatically to the model. Since it's all about the Interests list, please show the  appropriate parts of the view and model.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a good candidate for editor templates. As always we start by designing a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<InterestViewModel> Interests { get; set; }
}

public class InterestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string InterestLabel { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Name = "john",
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
            Place = "Spain",
            Interests = new[]
            {
                new InterestViewModel { Id = 1, InterestLabel = "cinema" },
                new InterestViewModel { Id = 2, InterestLabel = "sport" },
                new InterestViewModel { Id = 3, InterestLabel = "books" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO: process the results here, the view model will be
        // correctly bound
        ....
    }
}
```

then a view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`)

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Place)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Place)
    </div>
    <h2>Interests</h2>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Interests)

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and a corresponding editor template which will be rendered for each element of the Interests collection (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/InterestViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model InterestViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsSelected, Model.InterestLabel)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.InterestLabel)
```

Comment: hi, how you'r linking `InterestViewModel.cshtml` to `Index.cshtml` i'm following exactly what you said, but i'm gettin' only values instead of checkbox's.. what i'm missing ??

Comment: It works by convention: inside the view model the `Interests` property  is of type `IEnumerable<InterestViewModel>` => asp.net mvc will search for a file `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/InterestViewModel.cshtml` because that's the type name used in the collection.

Comment: yeah exactly thank you.. just a sec ago i search'd about `EditorTemplates` i was not aware of this..